# using ref or out modifiers with params modifier C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code here and I know that this will not compile as I am trying to use the ref modifier with the params modifier:

```
public static int[] Findfactors(ref params int[] pro) {

    int[] hjk = { 88, 99 };
    pro = hjk;
    return pro;
}
```

I am just trying to make the "pro" point to the "hjk" but I can not do that.
Why does't C# allow us to do that? why can't I use ref or out with params?

My best guess is the following:

The params has a property where it lets you not to pass any argument to a parameter that has the params modifier and so ,

with the example of this case, if I would not pass any argument to "pro" and then try to make pro point to "hjk", I would literally make "Nothing" point to something which would obviously not make any sense.

Comment: `params` is an input-only concept. `ref` would likely modify a temporary local variable (generated by the compiler) that the caller never saw. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Your title says "ref or out", so why not just use `out`? You also can't use it with `params`, but you can add a second parameter for it. `Findfactors(out int[] values, params int[] pro)`. Personally I don't see a reason to use either one of them in this case. I would just get rid of `ref` and return the value like you're doing anyway.

Comment: The purpose behind the params is to allow you to pass an arbitrary number of parameters from the calling function. If you're passing an integer array then you don't need to include the params token. If you want to modify an existing integer array then keep it as a ref, otherwise create a new array within the method and use the out token

Comment: You also cannot reassign a ref value, the original pointer is returned from the function and your reassignment is lost within the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try to think through why this feature doesn't work.

Start with a program that does work:

```
void Main()
{
    int x = 1;
    Console.WriteLine(Calc(ref x));
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}

public int Calc(ref int x)
{
    x = 42;
    return x + x;
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
84
42
```

Now let's imagine that the `ref params` combination worked. I could perhaps then write this:

```
void Main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    Console.WriteLine(Calc(ref x, ref y));
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.WriteLine(y);
}

public int Calc(ref params int[] z)
{
    z = new int[] { 2, 3, };
    return z.Sum();
}
```

It seems reasonable that the assignment of `z` would result in assigning back the values of `2` & `3` to `x` and `y`, respectively.

However, there's nothing stopping me writing any of the following:

```
    z = new int[] { };
    z = new int[] { 2, };
    z = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, };
```

All of those would cause the assignment of `x` & `y` to not work.

Hence this feature cannot work.

The only way to make this work is to ensure you have two values and two values only and if you want that within a single variable then you must use tuples.

Here's how:

```
void Main()
{
    (int x, int y) z = (1, 2);
    Console.WriteLine(Calc(ref z));
    Console.WriteLine(z.x);
    Console.WriteLine(z.y);
}

public int Calc(ref (int x, int y) z)
{
    z = (2, 3);
    return z.x + z.y;
}
```

That works and outputs the following:

```
5
2
3
```